# Security Essentials tray icon disapeared?

Tags: icons, notification-area, ms-security-essentials

I've been running Microsoft Security Essentials for quite a while. And I've just noticed that the tray icon has disapeared. I've checked every setting in the program, Windows Action Center claims that the program is running fine, taskmanager reports that the program is running and the context menu item in Windows Explorer works.

Everything indicates that the program is working. It's just that the tray icon is missing. And yes I've looked behind the little up arrow in Windows 7.

Any suggestions as to why the icon disapeared? Perhaps the program isn't supposed to show it anymore when it's running fine?

Comment: Try ending the msseces process in task manager and then restart MSE??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, this is due to the notification settings of Windows.

Right click on the Clock in the bottom right (default, unless you've moved your taskbar), and then click on 'Customize Notification Icons'.

In that list that comes up, next to the one that states `Microsoft Security Client User Interface` change the option to `Show Icon and Notifications`.

Once you click OK, the icon should come back.  If not, I'd just re-install the application, and then do the step above.

Comment: When I do that I get a message that says "This notification icon is not currently active". When I tried what ahmet said above, the icon shows up. But only until I reboot my computer.

Comment: I would uinstall MSSE (microsoft security essentials), reboot your PC, and reinstall.  This would essentially reset the programs options, and make windows treat it like a new application install.